# Adjust jQuery Fancybox' iframe height dynamically according to changed contents inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, height, fancybox

I'm using jQuery Fancybox to display forms in a modal window. I'm using the following code:

```
$("a.iframe").fancybox({
'padding': 0,
'width': 650,
'showCloseButton': false,
'hideOnContentClick': false,
'transitionIn': 'elastic',
'transitionOut': 'elastic',
'onComplete': function () {
  $('#fancybox-frame').load(function () {
    $('#fancybox-content').height($(this).contents().find('body').height() + 20);
  });
}
});
```

With the additional onComplete function, I'm able to adjust the height of the iframe accordingly to the height of the contents inside.

However, I've hidden a few elements with jQuery's .hide() inside the iframe. Whenever I want to .show() these elements, the iframe itself doesn't resize along with the extra height of the now visible elements.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: I think this trend has the answer to your request:
[Problem Adjusting Fancybox Iframe Overlay Width and Height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048216/problem-adjusting-fancybox-iframe-overlay-width-and-height)

Answer (score 2):

Put the following function to the page

```
$.fn.ResizeFancy = function(){
   $('#fancybox-content').height($('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('body').height() + 20);
};
```

After, trigger this function to your showHide function. For example;

```
function yourShowHideFn(){
    //bla bla bla

    $.fn.ResizeFancy();
}
```